# Powerpivot connect db2 : A TCPIP socket error has occured (10061)

Tags: excel, sockets, db2, powerpivot

I tried to use POWERPIVOT import table Wizard ,in order to import data from the db2. But face error in the connection:
here is the image:
[image]

can someone help me how can i solve it?

Comment: Have you tried a `telnet` on that connection port? Do you get a prompt or a connection refused?

Comment: sry , use telnet to connect which port? i don't know the port number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a ODBC for the db2 , and connect the powerpivot to the ODBC. And can already.